# Is cycling killing me? Excessive congestion

Tags: health, fitness, heart-rate

For lack of insight elsewhere I thought I'd turn to the this active Exchange to see if others have had similar experiences with their respiratory system while cycling. (note: I have already seen a doctor multiple times, not looking for trusted medical advice, just opinions and perspectives).

I've been cycling for 4 seasons. First couple of seasons were fine, I had no real issues. Then last season started well (albeit much more aggressive training) until I soon began experiencing sinus and chest congestion after every ride which developed into pneumonia in the beginning of Fall.

After a hospital stay and most of the winter off, I slowly got back on the trainer and worked up to my previous level of fitness (~6-10 hrs of riding a week and racing multiple times a season). Now, I'm beginning to experience the same type of congestion issues that previously "turned into" pneumonia.

Constant throat clearing and coughing. Half a box of tissues throughout the day and lots of snot/phlegm on the bike. My doctor and a pulmonary therapist suggested that I have activity induced asthma and gave me an inhaler + allergy/asthma medicine. This seems to ease the symptoms a little, but still they persist.

Any similar experiences out there?

Comment: Where are you cycling? When I used to commute from NYC to my job in the suburbs, I would see folks jogging and running alongside a major highway (FDR Drive) only feet from pollution-belching automobiles. Brief Google searches produced contradictory results about exercising in polluted air, but in general I'd say that polluted air is not all that healthy to breath in, especially whilst exercising. [This article](http://www.sparetheair.com/health.cfm) is pretty clear.

Comment: If I'm riding road, I ride in the mornings when there is very little, almost no traffic and then in the woods on my MTB. It was suggested that it could be intense allergies, but I have allergies as well and the two don't seem to coincide.

Comment: The first couple of seasons were fine. Last season started well and then you developed symptoms. Our bodies change over time and it might be the cycling but it sounds like the cycling is a known factor - what changed in your life that could impact respiration?

Comment: I would guess you either have pollen/dust allergies or you're simply not drinking enough water.  Remember, when you exercise to any significant degree you need to up your water intake, even if you don't feel that you're sweating.

Comment: @DavidD Good thinking! The one thing that I've been considering is a day of that first problematic season where I cleaned some mold in a room. But the exposure was acute and I am no longer exposed nor was I exposed to it before that day (and the symptoms did not go away during 3 months away from that environment).

Comment: @DanielRHicks that's good advice - I will up my water intake as I actually don't drink a ton usually. (1.5 bottle during a 20mph avg century, for example)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Pneumonia is an infection of the lungs; asthma isn't an infection. So which was it? In any case, I don't see an actually answerable question, here. As you're aware, we don't give health advice and "Any simliar experiences?" is a survey, not an objectively answerable question.

Comment: Sounds to me like cycling is aggravating some other condition.   Or possibly you're worn down and tired... Consider seeing another doctor for a second opinion.   This is definitely off topic for this site sorry.

Comment: @unpollo - Yeah, you should be drinking at least twice that.

Comment: Quite possible this is a symptom of overtraining.  Hard training sessions compromise the immune system, which makes it very easy for you to pick up sinus infections etc.
I'd say rest until the symptoms are clear and then restart very cautiously.  Avoid other people where possible for an hour or two after your hardest rides

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I did get some blood work done and there were indications in it that show a weakened immune system. I've considered this and will begin 1) easing off training, 2) drinking more water while riding, and 3) taking supplements that are theorized to boost the immune system (zinc, vitamin D [prescribed by doctor], and probiotics).